# How can i pass a value to a label from a database based on the users details

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have a login table with each user having different roles eg Staff, Admin.
I can have the user log in sucessfully with their username displaying between pages on the console application.
I am trying to Add in a new label  beside the username label so upon login the next page will have something like this  Admin: Johny  or Staff: Bob

What i have tried to do is Change the query to:

> "SELECT Role From User_Table WHERE eb_number='" + usernametxt.Text + "' and Password = '" + textBox1.Text + "'",con);

but this does not work either.

```
private void loginbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    //GRANT ACCESS TO THE DATABASE WITH USERNAME AND PASSWORD WHICH IS STORED IN THE DATABASE.
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString);
    con.Open();
    if (con.State==System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
    {
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT Count(*) From User_Table WHERE eb_number='" + usernametxt.Text + "' and Password = '" + textBox1.Text + "'",con);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        sda.Fill(dt);
        if (dt.Rows[0][0].ToString() == "1")
        {
            this.Hide();

            Main ss = new Main(usernametxt.Text); //usernametxt is passed in to prevent error
            ss.Show();
            MessageBox.Show("Logged in sucessfully");

        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Incorrect Username/Password Combination. Try Again");
        }
    }
}
```

Main.cs

```
    public Main(string Username/*, string Role*/) //passing username values 
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Username_lbl.Text = Username;  //Displaying  username 
        //Main_Role_lbl.Text = Role;
```

At he minute my code Just lets me log in and out reading the username and passwords.  I am unsure if i can add in to search for the Role for the username in the SQL query this way?  What i expected it the code to do was have a login like Admin: Johny or Staff: Bob

Comment: The same way you call SQL and check the result to see if the user/password is correct, you can just call another piece of SQL to get the role.

Comment: Off-topic but necessary advice about your code: - Use parameters in your queries instead of string concatenation. - Do not store passwords as clear text in the db, use a hashing function to calculate the password hash and save that instead. - Always dispose your connection object. Please do some research about the topics mentioned above.

Comment: Would have been easier if you had some kind of a relationship between Users and Roles table, when logging in you would fetch the ID(or every column) of the user and make it globally available, if fetching result != null that means your user exists and you are good to go. After that you have an ID, if you need to know what is the role for the User you just fetch the data from Roles table where ID = your globally available ID. Queries would look something like this:"select * from Users where Username = @username and password = @password" and "select RoleName from Roles where UserID = @userID"

Comment: First query gives you the Username, second gives you the role, now you have to just pass it to your form.

Comment: First, use parameterized queries. Imagine [what will happen](https://www.xkcd.com/327/) if someone enters `'; drop table users;--` in `textBox1`. Second, don't write your own authentication code. Passwords are never stored in cleartext or encrypted. They are salted, hashed for at least 1000 iterations using a cryptographic hash algorithm and only the hash is stored

Comment: Someone could also enter `' 1=1` as a password. Or `' or Role='Admin'`.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos +1 for the xkcd reference! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go something similar to your implementation:

```
private void loginbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var conString = "ReplaceWithMyConnectionString";
    string userRole = null;

    using (var con = new SqlConnection(conString))
    {
        con.Open();

        var cm = con.CreateCommand();
        cm.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
        cm.CommandText = "SELECT TOP 1 Role FROM User_Table WHERE eb_number = @eb_number AND and Password = @Password";
        cm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@eb_number", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, 50) { Value = usernametxt.Text });
        cm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Password", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, 50) { Value = textBox1.Text });

        using (var reader = cm.ExecuteReader(System.Data.CommandBehavior.SingleRow))
        {
            if (reader.Read())
            {
                userRole = reader["Role"].ToString();
            }
        }
    }

    if (userRole != null)
    {
        this.Hide();

        Main ss = new Main(usernametxt.Text, userRole); //usernametxt is passed in to prevent error
        ss.Show();
        MessageBox.Show("Logged in sucessfully");
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Incorrect Username/Password Combination. Try Again");
    }
}
```

There are a few things that are different, I'll explain the reason behind them:

- I replaced with parameters the string concatenation you were doing on your SQL. This is to avoid SQL injection. Have you wondered
  what would happen if the user enters the character `'` in the
  username or password textboxes? there's more to this, please research this subject.
- I'm instantiating your connection inside a `using` statement. This will make sure that your connection is closed (disposed) when we are done with the db stuff.
- Replaced the DataAdapter/DataTable with a leaner SqlCommand/SqlDataReader classes.
- I separated the logic in a way that the connection can be closed asap, and is not being interrupted by the call to MessageBox.Show().

Also, and very important, never store your passwords as clear text in the database, please do some research about hashing functions and why they should be used in this context.

I hope this helps.

Comment: This works.  had to change the SQL statement as there is has 2 "AND"'s in it but it works perfectly.